# Why is appengine serving an old version of my nodejs express app on https but the latest one properly on http appspot?

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-flexible

I have run `gcloud app deploy` many times over the past 12 hours. When I run `gcloud app browse` my browser opens up `https://mysite.appspot.com` with some old version of my app from hours ago. I Can't even tell which at this point.  However, if I visit `http://mysite.appspot.com` (wihout TLS) I get my new, expected version.

I've restarted the versions with the GCP console but have had no success in seeing my latest version at `https://mysite.appspot.com`. The console even says that the proper version is `serving` with 100% allocation, and indeed it is, over at `http` but not at `https`.

my app.yaml has only these 2 lines per [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml)

`env: flex
runtime: nodejs`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does the `protoPayload.versionId` field in the Stackdriver logs show which version is serving the https requests?

Comment: emptied browser cache?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @danielx. I'm pretty new to GPC and afraid I can't find the text `protoPayload' in what I think are the Stackdriver "logs" under "logging".

Anyway.. all seems right now. I ran another deploy and it was there straight away.

Looks like I might need to recall the infrastructure staff that I let go when I moved my little side project to PaaS. :)